# Blank or half-loaded PDF when opened by UIDocumentInteractionController (iOS 10.3)

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, ios10, ios10.3

We are using UIDocumentInteractionController to display PDF preview in our app. It worked perfectly before upgrade to iOS 10.3. Now by opening document it either shows only one page or the complete blank document.

PDF-file is stored in app cache directory (albeit using documents dir did not help either).

I can export PDF from preview to iBooks and it's perfectly displayed, so the file itself is not corrupted.

Any hints?

Comment: Current guess is that has something to do with change to APFS in iOS 10.3. I've encountered in internet single reports for PDFs not opening from other apps like mail, but still no official bug report or solid reference.

Comment: Currently we created a workaround by opending UIWebView with PDF inside as Pop Up - at least users can see their documents again, but no export or print them as from UIDocumentInteractionController

Answer (score 0):

iOS 10.3 has an issue about assian or accented characters on paths, due to it's new filesystem. So maybe you have to check filenames to avoid that

I saw this on https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2315863 and it was the solution for me

Comment: Thanks, forgot to mention we have verified that hypothesis, too - our file and path names were plain ASCII